# Flow type & Styled-components errors when imported

Tags: flowtype, styled-components, flow-typed

I'm on win 7.
Code:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

Errors:

> ```
> ... many lines of errors
> Error: node_modules/styled-components/lib/utils/create-broadcast.js.flow:20
>  20:       listeners.forEach(listener => listener(currentValue))
>                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ unused
>
> function argument
>  10:   subscribe: (listener: () => void) => () => void
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^ function type expects no arguments
>
> Error: node_modules/styled-components/lib/utils/create-broadcast.js.flow:26
>  26:       listener(currentValue)
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ unused function argument
>  10:   subscribe: (listener: () => void) => () => void
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^ function type expects no arguments
>
> Error: node_modules/styled-components/lib/utils/getComponentName.js.flow:4
>   4: export default function getComponentName(target: ReactClass<*>): string {
>                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ identifier `ReactClass`. Could not resolve name
>
>
> Found 24 errors
> error Command failed with exit code 2
> ```

.flowconfig:

```
[ignore]
./build/.*
./node_modules/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
suppress_comment=.*\\$FlowFixMe

[strict]
```

The package.json file is below:

```
"flow-typed": "^2.2.3",
"flow-bin": "^0.59.0",
"styled-components": "2.0.0",
```

Used project scaffold from https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate @ 3.5.0

I saw in a comment to use libdef 1.4, but when I run yarn add --dev flow-typed@1.4 I only get version 1 or version 2.x.x, but no 1.4.

What to do next?

Comment: You can ignore _node_modules_ in your _.flowconfig_ Or better include only what you need

Comment: @AlekseyL. Updated my question.

Comment: can you try `.*/node_modules/.*`

Comment: I'm impressed, that worked! Please put as an answer and I'll mark as correct. Maybe you can explain what happens when you do with `*` or without so other people can easily understand. thanks a lot! @AlekseyL.

Comment: You're welcome. `.*` goes for anything, see explanation below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want flow to stop checking *node_modules* you can either ignore them in *.flowconfig* or include only your source files.

To ignore everything in *node_modules*:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
```

Pay attention:

> These regular expressions match against absolute paths. They probably should start with .*

More info [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/ignore/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, the highlighted note I think is very useful.